# Add a popup with error, warning to shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Is there any way to add a **popup** (a closable window) with a warning or other message in **Shiny** - the R package I use to build my web application?

I have been searching for some time but without any results.

Comment: [Related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868002)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Although I don't think there is anything natively available in `shiny`, you can try adding `jQueryUI` to your application and using the Dialog widget. See http://jqueryui.com/dialog/.

(Un?)fortunately, you'll be forced to write some JavaScript to make it work.

---

Per @GSee's suggestion, here's a very minimal example of what it takes to make it work.

You'll need to download [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) and set up a shiny project with a structure like so:

```
.
├── server.R
├── ui.R
└── www
    ├── css
    │   └── jquery-ui.css
    ├── images
    │   ├── animated-overlay.gif
    │   ├── ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png
    │   ├── ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png
    │   ├── ui-bg_glass_55_fbf9ee_1x400.png
    │   ├── ui-bg_glass_65_ffffff_1x400.png
    │   ├── ui-bg_glass_75_dadada_1x400.png
    │   ├── ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png
    │   ├── ui-bg_glass_95_fef1ec_1x400.png
    │   ├── ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png
    │   ├── ui-icons_222222_256x240.png
    │   ├── ui-icons_2e83ff_256x240.png
    │   ├── ui-icons_454545_256x240.png
    │   ├── ui-icons_888888_256x240.png
    │   └── ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240.png
    └── js
        └── jquery-ui.js
```

(all of the image icons come part of jQueryUI)

Next, add a file called `scripts.js` (or whatever you like) to the `www/js` folder, containing the following

```
$( function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog();
})
```

This calls the `jQueryUI` `dialog` initializer on the element with id `dialog`.

Next, have a `server.R` and `ui.R` as follows:

```
server.R
--------
library(shiny)
shinyServer( function(input, output, session) {

  ## a very unsafe, basic access to the R console
  output$dialog <- renderPrint({

    code <- input$console
    output <- eval( parse( text=code ) )
    return(output)

  })

})
```

and

```
ui.R
----

library(shiny)

shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  includeCSS("www/css/jquery-ui.css"),  

  includeScript("www/js/jquery-ui.js"),
  includeScript("www/js/scripts.js"),

  textInput("console", "Enter an R Command"),
  uiOutput("dialog")

))
```

Now, if you do `runApp()`, you should see the results of evaluation of any code you write into the text input `console` appearing in the `dialog` box.

Now, the question is, how can we minimize it, or only show it when, say, error code is produced? That I'll have to leave for you, because I think it'll be tricky. Some options:

1. Figure out how to get our R code to send, or trigger, some JavaScript to show or hide the element. An example (not mine) using this to temporarily disable a button is [here](https://gist.github.com/xiaodaigh/6810928).
2. Attach a (JavaScript) observer or trigger to the output produced, and if you see an error (or output otherwise conforming in some way), show the box; otherwise hide it.
3. Generate an actual Shiny input/output pair to handle behavior as desired. (Brief tutorial at http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#building-inputs)

If you want to get a bit more out of your jQueryUI dialog, you can also try the extension jQuery-dialogextend [here](https://github.com/ROMB/jquery-dialogextend).

And, disclaimer: the console here is only for demonstrative purposes; please don't put any shiny apps that run unsanitized code from the user into the wild!

Comment: This would be an excellent answer if you showed an example shiny app that uses a Dialog widget

Answer (score 15):

There is this new R package out there - shinyBS which brings many twitter bootstrap functionality into shiny like alerts, tooltips, popovers, modal dialogs, progress bars etc...

[shinyBS](http://ebailey78.github.io/shinyBS/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Bolaka is right, install and load the `shinyBS` package, then run `bsExample("Alerts")` to see an example with code you can copy and paste.