# Create a pop-up menu with right click about an object

Tags: r, shiny

I want to know if it is possible create a pop-up menu with right click in a web page using R-Shiny, and how create menu with submenus?

I was testing with this code but does not work:

```
selectInput("variable", "Variable:",
        c(selectInput("variable1",Cylinders",c("cyl"="pm,"mmm"="jj"),
          "Transmission" = "am",
          "Gears" = "gear"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a package called [shinyBS](http://ebailey78.github.io/shinyBS/index.html) that adds many twitter bootstrap components to the shiny interface.

I've been working on an update that adds new menu-creating functions, one of which is to create right-click context menus in shiny apps. The update isn't ready for release yet but if you want to see where it stands you can install the 'menu-integration' branch of shinyBS from github:

`devtools::install_github("shinyBS", "ebailey78", "menu-integration")`

once installed, you can see the demo I've been working on by running:

`shinyBS::bsDemo("menubar")`

Right-click the plot to see the context menu in action... I would love any feedback you have!

Comment: Thank you!!, it's just what i was looking for, i am going to test your package, for create this menus in my GUI :)... I will comment you anything

Comment: do you know if is possible change of display without using tabs but using the popup menu for change different displays?

Comment: @Eric 
do you know if there is a way to restrict the native right click behavior. There are two menus which pop up for me when i right click: the native mac right click and the applications right click.